# how to add mutilple categories in a item in joomla 2.5

Tags: components, joomla2.5

I am trying to build a component in Joomla where I want an item to be in multiple categories.

Whenever I select ]multiple=multiple in xml form, and Submit the form, catid is set   to    zero.

```
//this is the code
    <code section>

  <field
 name="catid"
 multiple="multiple"
 type="category">
<option value="0">JOPTION_SELECT_CATEGORY</option>
</field>
How do I achieve that?

Secondly where is code to insert catid values in db.
protected function loadFormData()
{
// Check the session for previously entered form data.
 $data = JFactory::getApplication()->getUserState('com_xyz.edit.xyz.data', array());
if (empty($data))
 {
  $data = $this->getItem();
   }
    print_r($data);
     return $data;
  }
```

Can anyone help me out in this...

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a custom "checkboxes" field instead of the "category" field as I don't think that it supports the "multiple" value.

I seems like [this thread is describing the same problem and has the solution](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=717387).